# How do you get a list of installed display languages?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, localization

I know which languages the OS is available in from the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202918%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) but I am looking for a way to retrieve this with code. [InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage.installedinputlanguages.aspx) doesn't seem to be available and I can't find its equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any API in Windows Phone that returns a list of installed/available languages. I did find out that switching to an unsupported CultureInfo on the current thread Current(UI)Culture throws an exception.

So it is possible to test a couple of cultures (I wouldn't test them all, but you could test for the languages you support) in an ugly way.

That said, I do think you should NOT (be able to) change the language in your program because it will confuse the user. The user will expect to change the language himself.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this.

```cs
public bool isCultureSupported(String culture)
{ 
  CultureInfo locale = new CultureInfo(culture);
  if (locale.CompareInfo == null)
    return false;

  return true;

}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO, here, it is a good practice to explain why to use your solution and not just how. That will make your answer more valuable and help further reader to have a better understanding of how you do it. I also suggest that you have a look on our FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: Note: This doesn't work on WP8. Checked with "ka-GE" (Georgian) which ist not supported currently according to MSDN but `CompareInfo` was not null.